# Is there a way to directly prepare data from excel tables to perform statistical tests in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, statistics

First of all, sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm rather new to R. Please bear with me and refer me to directions where I can learn better.

I imported the following data from a .csv file

```
> View(teste01)
> teste01 <- as.matrix(teste01)
> class(teste01)
[1] "matrix" "array" 
> teste01
      X1                                TOTAL SURVIVOR FATAL
 [1,] "<40 years"                       " 7"  " 6"     " 1" 
 [2,] "40-60 years"                     "28"  "17"     "11" 
 [3,] "≥60 years"                       "39"  "13"     "25" 
 [4,] "Female"                          "38"  "17"     "19" 
 [5,] "Male"                            "36"  "19"     "16" 
 [6,] "Previous hospitalisation"        "40"  "21"     "19" 
 [7,] "Hypertension"                    "41"  "17"     "24" 
 [8,] "Diabetes"                        "29"  "12"     "17" 
 [9,] "Obesity"                         "19"  "10"     " 9"
```

I'm looking for a way to do a Chi-squared test on it, but by using `chisq.test(teste01)`, I get the following output:
Error: all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite in chisq.test

By reading similar questions, I've come to think that you basically have to create a matrix from zero on R. Is that right? If it's not, is there a way to directly use data from a .csv and/or .xlsx files? In my example, how would that be?

**DATA**

```
> dput(teste01)
structure(c("<40 years", "40-60 years", "≥60 years", "Female", 
"Male", "Previous hospitalisation", "Hypertension", "Diabetes", 
"Obesity", "Past smoking history", "Respiratory diseases", "Cardiovascular disease", 
"Gastrointestinal diseases", "Central Nervous System diseases", 
"Liver diseases", "Past surgery history", "Chronic heart disease", 
"Cancer", "Fatigue", "Fever", "Dyspnoea", "Cough", "Coryza", 
"Myalgia", "Chest pain", "Pharyngalgia", "Diarrhoea", "Nausea and Vomit", 
"Previously hospitalisation", "Diagnosed sepsis by ICU team", 
" 7", "28", "39", "38", "36", "40", "41", "29", "19", " 9", " 9", 
" 5", " 5", "11", " 7", "10", "14", " 9", "10", "29", "50", "32", 
" 7", "11", " 6", " 5", " 9", " 6", "40", "14", " 6", "17", "13", 
"17", "19", "21", "17", "12", "10", " 3", " 4", " 2", " 2", " 4", 
" 2", " 4", " 6", " 5", " 4", "15", "23", "18", " 2", " 7", " 3", 
" 2", " 2", " 2", "21", " 4", " 1", "11", "25", "19", "16", "19", 
"24", "17", " 9", " 6", " 5", " 3", " 3", " 7", " 5", " 6", " 8", 
" 4", " 6", "14", "27", "14", " 5", " 4", " 3", " 3", " 7", " 4", 
"19", "10"), .Dim = c(30L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", 
"TOTAL", "SURVIVOR", "FATAL")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe `x` should be a numeric vector or `matrix`.  Here, it is a `matrix`, but it is a `character` matrix as the first column is `character`.  We can make the matrix numeric with the row names attribute from the first column.  Now, the `chisq.test` should work

```
teste02 <- teste01[,-1]
teste02[] <- as.numeric(teste02)
class(teste02) <- 'numeric'
row.names(teste02) <- teste01[,1]
chisq.test(teste02)
#Pearson's Chi-squared test

#data:  teste02
#X-squared = 23.115, df = 58, p-value = 1
```

Comment: It worked wonderfully. Thank you so much. I literally could not find an answer and I've been struggling all day with it. Does the same logic apply if I'm trying to go for a Fisher test or whatever test which depends on tables?

Comment: @dairelix From my experience, it is better to always check 1) `str(yourdata)` first before even thinking about any transformation as it can give lots of clues, 2) check the help page of the function to be applied `?chisq.test`.  The description and arguments in help files gives an indication what the function expects and what you have from the `str`.  Then, it becomes easier to pinpoint the error when it happens

Comment: I'm taking your advice as gold. Once again, thank you so much. You literally saved me hours of work today and in the future.